# How to matricize a vector?

Tags: matrix, vector

I am wondering how to represent a vector as a matrix, using specified dimensions. For example, `MatrixForm[{a, b, c, d}]` gives me a column vector. But I would want something like `MatrixForm[{a, b, c, d},{2,2}]` So that it gives me output like:
$\left(\begin{matrix}a , b \\ c,d \end{matrix}\right)$. I am flexible as to whether it uses row major or column major conventions, i.e. whether to traverse rows or columns first.

Quick edit: how does this answer change, when I know the matrix is symmetric?

Thank you so much!

Comment: `ArrayReshape`.

Comment: Ah thank you! and if I want to build a symmetric matrix, is there a way to do this using this function, as well?

Comment: Yes. If the entries of the vector fit to the ones of a symmetric matrix, the resulting matrix will be symmetric of course. But better have a look at `SymmetrizedArray`; maybe that is what you are looking for.

Comment: `{a, b, c, d} // Partition[#,2]&`

Comment: Note: `MatrixForm` is purely for display purposes, and so if you are doing actual calculations, don't use it.